# Using dplyr to categorize object in two columns of dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, categorization

Hi I have a sample data frame shown below:

```
   Policy_Holder_ID Insured_ID
   <chr>            <chr>     
 1 ID27343          ID215664  
 2 ID27310          ID27310   
 3 ID27343          ID205729  
 4 ID27343          ID205728  
 5 ID27348          ID205734  
 6 ID27348          ID205735  
 7 ID27315          ID205719  
 8 ID27315          ID27315   
 9 ID27345          ID205731  
10 ID27345          ID205733  
11 ID27345          ID27345   
12 ID2731           ID2731    
13 ID27310          ID205714  
14 ID27310          ID205715
```

**Sorry if it's not in `dput` form. I tried to use this function but didn't get a right result for it**

What I want to is to categorize this data frame into 3 different categories as listed below:

1. Group 1: those policy holders who **only** insured themselves. In other words, **Policy_Holder_ID** and **Insured_ID** are the same (example : ID2731)
2. Group 2: those policy holders who only bought insurance for other people. In other words, they are listed in **Policy_Holder_ID** but not in **Insured_ID** and have 1 or more **Insured_ID** (example: ID27343)
3. Group 3: those policy holders who purchased insurance for themselves and other people (example: ID27310)

So the output should look like this:

```
   Policy_Holder_ID Insured_ID    group
   <chr>            <chr>     
 1 ID27343          ID215664         2
 2 ID27310          ID27310          3
 3 ID27343          ID205729         2
 4 ID27343          ID205728         2
 5 ID27348          ID205734         2
 6 ID27348          ID205735         2
 7 ID27315          ID205719         3
 8 ID27315          ID27315          3  
 9 ID27345          ID205731         3
10 ID27345          ID205733         3
11 ID27345          ID27345          3  
12 ID2731           ID2731           1  
13 ID27310          ID205714         3 
14 ID27310          ID205715         3
```

I was hoping that you can provide a time-saving solution other than using the `for` loop for the data. My original data has more than 400000 rows so for loop doesn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `case_when` after grouping by 'Policy_Holder_ID'.  Based on the description, if we have `all` elements of 'Insured_ID' matches the 'Policy_Holder_ID' , then return 1, if none of them matches (`!=` -> again with `all`), then return 2, and the default option should return 3.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Policy_Holder_ID) %>%
  mutate(group = case_when(all(Insured_ID == Policy_Holder_ID) ~ 1, 
          all(Insured_ID != Policy_Holder_ID)~ 2, 
       TRUE ~ 3)) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
#   Policy_Holder_ID Insured_ID group
#   <chr>            <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 ID27343          ID215664       2
# 2 ID27310          ID27310        3
# 3 ID27343          ID205729       2
# 4 ID27343          ID205728       2
# 5 ID27348          ID205734       2
# 6 ID27348          ID205735       2
# 7 ID27315          ID205719       3
# 8 ID27315          ID27315        3
# 9 ID27345          ID205731       3
#10 ID27345          ID205733       3
#11 ID27345          ID27345        3
#12 ID2731           ID2731         1
#13 ID27310          ID205714       3
#14 ID27310          ID205715       3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Policy_Holder_ID = c("ID27343", "ID27310", "ID27343", 
"ID27343", "ID27348", "ID27348", "ID27315", "ID27315", "ID27345", 
"ID27345", "ID27345", "ID2731", "ID27310", "ID27310"), Insured_ID = c("ID215664", 
"ID27310", "ID205729", "ID205728", "ID205734", "ID205735", "ID205719", 
"ID27315", "ID205731", "ID205733", "ID27345", "ID2731", "ID205714", 
"ID205715")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, can you please explain, why you added `all` inside `case_when`?

Comment: @Roozbeh_you I updated the post.  Please tell me if that is the logic you wanted

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` option using nested `ifelse`

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  group := ifelse(
    all(Policy_Holder_ID == Insured_ID),
    1,
    ifelse(
      !unique(Policy_Holder_ID) %in% Insured_ID,
      2,
      3
    )
  ),
  Policy_Holder_ID
]
```

gives

```
> df
    Policy_Holder_ID Insured_ID group
 1:          ID27343   ID215664     2
 2:          ID27310    ID27310     3
 3:          ID27343   ID205729     2
 4:          ID27343   ID205728     2
 5:          ID27348   ID205734     2
 6:          ID27348   ID205735     2
 7:          ID27315   ID205719     3
 8:          ID27315    ID27315     3
 9:          ID27345   ID205731     3
10:          ID27345   ID205733     3
11:          ID27345    ID27345     3
12:           ID2731     ID2731     1
13:          ID27310   ID205714     3
14:          ID27310   ID205715     3
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Policy_Holder_ID = c("ID27343", "ID27310", "ID27343",
"ID27343", "ID27348", "ID27348", "ID27315", "ID27315", "ID27345",
"ID27345", "ID27345", "ID2731", "ID27310", "ID27310"), Insured_ID = c("ID215664",
"ID27310", "ID205729", "ID205728", "ID205734", "ID205735", "ID205719",
"ID27315", "ID205731", "ID205733", "ID27345", "ID2731", "ID205714",
"ID205715")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3",
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Find out which are same and which are not same
df1 <- df %>% filter(Policy_Holder_ID == Insured_ID) %>% mutate(group = 1)
df2 <- df %>% filter(Policy_Holder_ID != Insured_ID) %>% mutate(group = 2)
# find out which are the common ones
common_Policy_Holder_ID <- intersect(df1$Policy_Holder_ID, df2$Policy_Holder_ID)
# if they are in common, then change the value of group
df <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% if_else(common_Policy_Holder_ID == Policy_Holder_ID, group = 3, group = group)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Roozbeh

Did you try to split this file into several files to compute more faster each one?

If others answers didn't work, you can try this:

Try to use **bigreadr** package. Try to do the steps bellow:

1. Save your dataframe into a .csv file;
2. Use **split_file** function to split - like this:

   split_file('your_file.csv', every_nlines = 'how much lines for each file'  , prefix_out = 'output's name', repeat_header = T)
3. Read each file to do for loop; and
4. Do a rbind to regroup all files into one.